# adduser and personalize path to /etc/passwd

Tags: linux, debian

Using linux I need create a new user but personalize the path of own home in /etc/passwd. For now I using:

```
adduser test0 --shell /bin/nologin --disabled-password  --no-create-home --quiet --force-badname --gecos ""
```

But in /etc/passwd I've

```
test0:x:1004:1005:,,,:/home/test0:/bin/nologin
```

I need somethinkg like this:

```
test0:x:1004:1005:,,,:/home/personal/test0:/bin/nologin
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `--home=...`? I couldn't test if it is interfering with `-no-create-home`, but accroding to man page: `--home DIR` _Use DIR as the user's home directory, rather  than  the  default
              specified  by the configuration file.  If the directory does not
              exist, it is created and skeleton files are copied._

Answer (score 2):

You can add the parameter `--home HOME_DIR` to define the home directory.

So the command line must be

```
adduser test0 --shell /bin/nologin --disabled-password --home /home/personal/test0 --no-create-home --quiet --force-badname --gecos ""
```

Comment: Thanks! On debian linux there's --home (and not --home-dir).

Comment: Changed the answer accordingly. Had only a fedora system and there it is `--home-dir`.

Comment: @PolHallen, that's because `adduser` is a non-standard higher-level wrapper over the `useradd` tool (which is sort of standardized).  Also please note there's no such thing as "debian linux" -- there's Debian (an OS, as well as, say, Fedora is), and there's Linux -- an OS kernel.